# Почему сбрасывается параметр в плагине polylang?

Tags: wordpress, polylang

Пытаюсь настроить **url** так, чтобы в зависимости от текущего языка они формировались подобным образом:

- mydomain.com/ru/адрес-1
- mydomain.com/ru/адрес-2
- mydomain.com/ru/

Для этого нужно включить настройку:

> The language is set from the directory name in pretty permalinks

Но она постоянно сбрасывается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто сталкивался с подобным, и какое решение может быть? Я определённо что - то делаю не так.

Comment: Отключите другие плагины и проверьте еще раз

Comment: @Krya спасибо за ответ, но у меня кроме SEO плагина, и ACF больше ничего не установлено. Попробовал SEO отключить, но безрезультатно.